# Find the deduction of car

Tags: linear-algebra

After deduction of 20% of the price of a car is 2628 euros. As the euro has been the descent.

My attemp is: $$S=2628$$
$$p=20%$$
$$i=?$$

$$S=\frac{100i}{p}\Rightarrow i=\frac{Sp}{100}=\frac{2628\cdot 20}{100}=525.6$$

$3183.6$ i.e. $S+i=3183.6$ euro.

Now, $$S_1=S+i=3183.6$$
$$p=20%$$
$$i=?$$
i.e.,
$$i=\frac{S_1p}{100}=\frac{3183,6\cdot 20}{100}=636.72$$

Price before discount has been $3264.72$ euro

But do not know whether I have resolved well. Please help me figure out whether my solution is correct.

Comment: No.  This is not correct.  The discount $(i)$ is 20% off applied to the original price $(S+i)$, not just $(S)$.  A simpler way would be to note that the new price is 80% of the original price and set up an equation from there.

Comment: can choose please

Comment: It is now correct.

Comment: No, it's still off.  the 525.6 and 3183.6 values are no good.  The method you are using would eventually approximate the correct answer if you kept applying it, but it is not a good method.  You need to restart with something along the lines of $x*.8=2628$ or $S-0.2S=2628$

Comment: $S-0.2S=2628\Rightarrow S=2920$. Price before discount has been $2920$. I hope, now it is correct.

Comment: It looks like you used 0.1 instead of 0.2  The answer should be 3285